# REST API call running fine over HTTPS for one programming language but not for others

Tags: java, rest, ssl, coldfusion, https

Well, I have been testing REST API calls recently using different programming languages like Coldfusion, PHP, Java, and ASP.NET I was using "http" initially in my URL initially for making an API call and all of the 
API calls were working fine in all the languages. Say for example my url was:

```
http://www.myapi.com/webapi/roothost/xyz
```

But now, recently, the ***box(IP corresponding to www.myapi.com)*** to which I was sending an API call has been operating on SSL so it should no longer support "http" but "https". This is also evident from the fact that when I try to send an api call in
Coldfusion using the old URL which was    `http://www.myapi.com/webapi/roothost/xyz` , it fails.

However, I am observing one weird phenomenon for other programming languages(JAVA,ASP.NET,PHP) are concerned. When I try to use "https" as my URL while testing through JAVA,ASP.NET and PHP, the API call fails and it still works with "http" which I don't want.
I am using WAMPSERVER, Netbeans 8 and Visual Studio 2012 to make an API call using PHP, JAVA and ASP.NET respectively.

Does anybody knows what could be the problem? Please advise

Comment: what errors are coming out of your other implementations? are you getting certificate errors? also, how is it failing http on CF but not on all the others? Usually you support it or you don't. I'm not sure why the same http call fails for one platform and not others

Comment: could you also please share your implementation.

Comment: Please share the URL to the server. We have no idea what's going on because there's no error message, no problematic code and and no URL to test against.

Comment: Java /ASP / PHP all work.  The problem is not with them. 1) Are your SSL certificates correct? are they self-issued or issued by a CA?  Are you sure that you are using the SSL connector in that given language correctly?  Maybe the SSL settings in Apache is using settings which are not supported in language X? or not by default?  It could literally be anything.

Comment: @baconoverlord 1) Yes my SSL certificates are correct. 2) They are issued by CA and not self issued. How can I make sure that I am using SSL connector, say for example in Java where I am using Netbeans 8 ?

Comment: For nio there are classes designed by others like http://www.rmiproxy.com/ScalableSSL/javadoc/scalablessl/SSLSocketChannel.html or the built in one  http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

Comment: @baconoverlord  If I understood you correctly, I would need to import the classe(s) in my java program that is/are mentioned in the [link]( http://www.rmiproxy.com/ScalableSSL/javadoc/scalablessl/SSLSocketChannel.html) you mentioned or the [another](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) you mentioned? Please advise. I am wondering if I would need to do some settings in my `web.xml` as mentioned over here in the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbxw.html) ?

Comment: Try using the SSLSocket that is built into Java.   Pick one language and post all the code on pastebin for us to look at.  Otherwise it is very hard for us to help you.